# Clone, Pull, Commit & Push Using libgit2 C

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I am working on windows 7 libgit2 version 0.23.0. I am using private repository to get clone using libgit2. I have read lot's of Questions & Answers from Stackoverflow, [samples](https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/101-samples/), github Issues/fixes which is available for libgit2 library.

I am able to clone private repository by setting credential using git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new() method. This method successfully pull all updated files from remote to my local disk. But after that if any changes is made on remote repository then I am getting issue to pull changes from remote to my local disk, I am using [fetch.c](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/ex/HEAD/network/fetch.html) it execute git_remote_fetch() without any error, it creates

1. New **FETCH_HEAD** file which contains new oid under /.git folder and
2. Download new pack files (.idx & .pack) as well  under /.git/objects/pack folder.

After all this, changes of files or updated files is not copying at my local repo, I am not sure if I am skipping any step to do that I also tried to commit & push the files from my local repo to remote repo but I am not able to get any good example for that. The samples & API are little bit confusing for me.

Please suggest me if any body can help me for simple:

1. Pull from origin or master branch
2. Commit local repository
3. Push to origin or master branch

**USING LIBGIT2**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fetching is not pulling. These are two different things. Fetch does not change your working directory in any way. Fetch just downloads missing commits from the remote repository.

Comment: `pull` == `fetch` + `merge`

Comment: Feedback on what is confusing in the documentation and the samples would be most welcome!

Comment: @EdwardThomson : for example [git_merge] (https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/merge/git_merge).  Could you please tell me any of the sample or example ? That really helps me.

Comment: Trying to call int git_merge(git_repository *repo, const git_annotated_commit **their_heads, size_t their_heads_len, const git_merge_options *merge_opts, const git_checkout_options *checkout_opts); 

But second parameter git_annotated_commit should be constant. I am getting git_annotated_commit **out from method git_annotated_commit_lookup() method. could anybody tell me how I can convert  git_annotated_commit **out as const ?

Comment: @EdwardThomson : Could you please suggest me on above comment?